# Angular-XEditable saving data automatically

Tags: angularjs

I used the option

```
buttons="no"
```

To remove the buttons from the text box, but now nothing gets saved. How can I save it to the model( maybe when I change focus? ) and call a scope method.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, it might benefit someone, although this is the first time using angular so its properly no the best;

```
e-ng-blur="saveName($data, entry)"


$scope.saveName = function(data, entry) {
    entry.name = data;
    return $http.post('/api/update/entry/', {name: data, id: entry.id})
  }
```